# Understanding pointers in assembly language

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, nasm

Are we enclosing the variable or register in brackets to specify a pointer in assembly?

Example1;

```
    MOV eax, array+4
    LEA eax, [array+4]
```

Example2;

```
section .data
    array DB 116,97

section .bss
    variable RESB 0

section .text
    global _start:

_start:
    mov eax,[array]

    ;exit
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

I am not getting any errors while compiling or running the above code. Is the address of the zero index of the array placed in the `EAX` register?

Example3;

```
    INC [variable]
```

When compiling the above code, I am getting the "operation size not specified" error. And why can't the command be used as `INC variable`?

Example4;

```
section .data
    array DB 116,97

section .bss
    variable RESB 97

section .text
    global _start:

_start:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,variable
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80

    ;exit
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

And this code is not working.

Comment: `[]` denotes a memory reference. Without it it's a literal number which can be an address. `nasm` doesn't keep track of variable types so you need to tell it the size if it can't be deduced. So `inc byte [variable]` will work. `inc variable` will not work as it would try to increment a literal constant (the address of `variable`). The final example #4 is working but you are printing a zero byte from `variable`. Maybe you meant `mov ecx, array`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about #4. Where exactly is my fault? Thank you for the other things. @Jester

Comment: It's unclear what you want example #4 to do. It does work. It prints the first byte of `variable` which is a binary zero. Maybe you wanted `db 97` and not `resb 97`? That can only work in `.data` as `.bss` is all zeroes. `resb 97` allocates 97 zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are we enclosing the variable or registrar in brackets to specify a
> pointer in assembly?
>
> Example1;
>
> ```
> MOV eax, array+4
> LEA eax, [array+4]
> ```

The brackets are like the dereference operator in C (`*ptr`). They get the value at the resulting address inside the square brackets. As for the example, both of these essentially do the same thing. The first moves the address of the `array` label + 4 into `eax`. The second uses `lea`, which loads the effective address of its source operand. So you get `array + 4`, dereference it, and get the address again with `lea` and load it into `eax`.

> Example2;
>
> ```
> section .data
>     array DB 116,97
>
> section .bss
>     variable RESB 0
>
> section .text
>     global _start:
>
> _start:
>     mov eax,[array]
>
>     ;exit
>     mov eax,1
>     int 0x80
> ```
>
> I am not getting any errors while compiling or running the above code.
> Is the address of the zero index of the array placed in the eax
> register?

Kind of. Since you're moving it into `eax`, a 32-bit register, it is assumed that you want to move the first 4 bytes at the address `array` into `eax`. But there are only 2 bytes at `array`: `116` and `97`. So this is probably not what you intended. To load the first byte at `array` into `eax`, do `movzx eax, BYTE [array]`, which will move `array[0]` into the LSByte of `eax` and zero out the higher bytes. `mov al, [array]` will also work, though it won't zero out the upper bytes.

> Example3;
>
> ```
> INC [variable]
> ```
>
> When compiling the above code, I am getting the "operation size not
> specified" error. And why can't the command be used as INC variable.

The error says it all. `variable` is just an address. When you use `[]`, how many bytes should it take? You need to specify a size. For example to get the first byte, you would do `inc BYTE [variable]`. However, from the previous example, it seems like you've reserved nothing at `variable`, so trying to access any bytes at it may cause some issue. As for "And why can't the command be used as `INC variable`", as I just said, `variable` is just a label which translates to some address. You can't change the address which `variable` translates to.

> Example4;
>
> ```
> section .data
>     array DB 116,97
>
> section .bss
>     variable RESB 97
>
> section .text
>     global _start:
>
> _start:
>     mov eax,4
>     mov ebx,1
>     mov ecx,variable
>     mov edx,1
>     int 0x80
>
>     ;exit
>     mov eax,1
>     int 0x80
> ```
>
> And this code is not working.

It may seem to not be printing anything, but it actually is. `.bss` zero-initializes any memory that you reserve. That means when you print the first byte at `variable`, it just prints the NUL character. However, this doesn't seem to be visible for you when you print it, so it seems like nothing has been printed.

(By the way, are you certain that you know what `resb` does? In one example, you reserve 0 bytes, and in another, you reserve 97 bytes for no apparent reason. You might want to take another look at what `resb` actually does.)

Comment: Thank you for everything. What should I do so that I can print the letter "a" in the last code? (using variable)

Comment: @yulaf_ve_abant RESB reserves bytes. Like I said, you'll want to take another look at what RESB does. For printing `'a'`, you'll probably want to replace your `variable resb 97` with a `variable db 97` in `.data` or `.rodata`.

Comment: Note that `mov eax, BYTE [array]` is invalid. You might have meant `movzx`.

Comment: Oh my god. I thought the data in the .data section was unchangeable. ok i got it, thank you. It was written at the address  [TutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm) that the data in the .data section cannot be changed.

Comment: @yulaf_ve_abant I don't know what's up about that, because you can :/ Though as I previously mentioned, `.rodata` is specifically there for data that cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3):

```
array            ; variable address
byte[array]      ; value of first byte of array
word[array]      ; value of first word of array
byte[array + 1]  ; value of second byte of array
```

Think of the variable names as pointers, and using `size[name]` gets the value being pointed (similar to `*name` in C where `name` is a pointer)

Comment: Asm labels work a lot like `extern char foo[]` in C - using the bare label name gives the address, unlike with other kinds of C variables where there's an implicit access to the memory.  `char *foo` in C would mean there's some data memory somewhere whose bytes hold the address; that's not the case with asm labels.